# Flutter - Nullability problem with Locale

Tags: flutter, locale, dart-null-safety

Below code has no compiler warnings or errors. Running it results in:

```
lib/main.dart:26:51: Error: The argument type 'Locale?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Locale' because 'Locale?' is nullable and 'Locale' isn't.
 - 'Locale' is from 'dart:ui'.
    thisAppsLocaleNotifier = ValueNotifier(window.locale);
                                                  ^
lib/main.dart:27:43: Error: Property 'languageCode' cannot be accessed on 'Locale?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'Locale' is from 'dart:ui'.
Try accessing using ?. instead.
    Localization.langCode = window.locale.languageCode;
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed to compile application.
```

Neither window nor locale could be null. No parameters here can be null. The error message is quite annoying because trying

```
thisAppsLocaleNotifier = ValueNotifier(window.locale ?? Locale('en'));
```

Results in a compiler warning:

```
The left operand can't be null, so the right operand is never executed.  Try removing the operator and the right operand.
```

This is the code:

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

import 'main.i18n.dart';

/// Supported locales. First entry `en` is default.
const List<Locale> supportedLocales = [
  Locale('en', 'US'),
  Locale('de', 'DE'),
  Locale('es', 'ES'),
];

late ValueNotifier<Locale> thisAppsLocaleNotifier;

/// Entry point for example application
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp() {
    thisAppsLocaleNotifier = ValueNotifier(window.locale);
    Localization.langCode = window.locale.languageCode;
  }

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: thisAppsLocaleNotifier,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Locale thisAppsLocale, Widget? child) =>
          MaterialApp(
        home: MyHomePage(),
        locale: thisAppsLocale,
        localizationsDelegates: [
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        supportedLocales: supportedLocales,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
        ),
        title: 'input_country',
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('_MyHomePageState build');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('App Title'.i18n),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('thisAppsLocale = ${thisAppsLocaleNotifier.value} / langCode ='
                ' ${Localization.langCode}'),
            ButtonBar(
              alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => setLocale(Locale('de')),
                  child: Text('de'),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => setLocale(Locale('en')),
                  child: Text('en'),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => setLocale(Locale('es')),
                  child: Text('es'),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void setLocale(Locale newLocale) {
    Localization.langCode = newLocale.languageCode;
    thisAppsLocaleNotifier.value = newLocale;
  }
}
```

And this is *pubspec.yaml*

```
name: qq
description: A new Flutter application.
publish_to: 'none'
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

**What is required to run the code in null-safety mode?**

This is the localization class *main.i18n.dart*:

```
extension Localization on String {
  static String langCode = 'en';

  String get i18n => localize(this, _t);

  static final Map<String, Map<String, String>> _t = {
    'All': {
      'de': 'Alle',
      'es': 'Todas',
    },
    'Example': {
      'de': 'Beispiel',
      'es': 'Ejemplo',
    },
    'Languages': {
      'de': 'Sprachen',
      'es': 'Idiomas',
    },
    'Selectables': {
      'de': 'Einträge',
      'es': 'Entradas',
    },
  };

  String localize(String english, Map<String, Map<String, String>> t10ns) {
    if (langCode != 'en') {
      Map<String, String>? _t10ns = t10ns[english];
      if (_t10ns == null) {
        print('No translations found for "$english"');
      } else {
        String? translated = _t10ns[langCode];
        if (translated == null) {
          print('Translation to language "$langCode" missing for "$english"');
        } else {
          return translated;
        }
      }
    }
    return english;
  }
}
```

Output of `Flutter doctor`:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.867], locale de-DE)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: I added a generic explanation of null safety without running your code in the answer below.  I tried to run your code but was obviously missing the file `main.i18n.dart`. Also I cannot find the definition of the Localization class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it was a bug with flutter web. It should be fixed in one of the next releases

https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/24922

---

What you can do for now to make it work on web and avoid warnings on desktop or mobiles:

Create 3 files:

- `shared.dart`
- `mobile.dart`
- `web.dart`

```dart
// shared.dart
export 'web.dart' if (dart.library.io) 'mobile.dart';
```

```dart
// mobile.dart
import 'dart:ui';

Locale getLocale() => window.locale;
```

```dart
// web.dart
import 'dart:ui';

// ignore: unnecessary_non_null_assertion
Locale getLocale() => window.locale!;
```

Then in your code, only import `shared.dart` and get the `Locale` from there:

```
main.dart
import 'shared.dart';

final Locale locale = getLocale();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a comprehensive explanation of null safety here: [Null safety in Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/null-safety). It includes a link to the migration guide that will help you migrate your code.

Note that in the pubspec:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

specifying the sdk version `>=2.12.0` enables null safety, with the consequent checks. Specifying any earlier version will disable null safety.

In order to fix your code for null safety, you need to check for non-null values where they are not permitted - the error messages generally point this out. So the errors:

```
lib/main.dart:26:51: Error: The argument type 'Locale?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Locale' because 'Locale?' is nullable and 'Locale' isn't.
 - 'Locale' is from 'dart:ui'.
    thisAppsLocaleNotifier = ValueNotifier(window.locale);

lib/main.dart:27:43: Error: Property 'languageCode' cannot be accessed on 'Locale?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'Locale' is from 'dart:ui'.
Try accessing using ?. instead.
    Localization.langCode = window.locale.languageCode;
```

can be fixed by asserting that the parameter is not null using `window.locale!`.

Your frustration with `window.locale ?? ...` was caused because this does not check for `window` being null.

Comment: OK. I changed first line to `thisAppsLocaleNotifier = ValueNotifier(window.locale!);` This results in a warning that the parameter cannot be null. It also cannot solve next line in any combination like 'Localization.langCode = window?.locale?.languageCode ?? 'en';` This does not work either. Maybe this problem does not have a solution due to a compiler bug?

Running "dart migrate" results in: "Nothing to do."

Comment: I tried to run your code but was obviously missing the file `main.i18n.dart`. Also I cannot find the definition of the `Localization` class

Comment: I commented out `main.i18.dart` and the missing `Localization` class, and used `window.locale!`. The compile gives warnings about the `!` being ignored, but the code **runs OK**. I went to Github ro research the spurious warning, and see you raised https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/79351 :)

Comment: The answer is slightly amiss. The main problem seems to be not null safety in itself but some transient problem with Flutter Web. The error message appears in a fully null-safe app that runs perfectly on Android and iOS. The same source gives the error in Web now.